# scala generics translated to java Object

Tags: java, scala, generics, scala-java-interop

I'm trying to use a scala class that extends a generic class from java, but java detects generic fields as Object instead of the types from the subclass.

Here's a minimal example:

scala:

```
class BaseClass[A] {
var a:A = _
def get():A = a

class OtherClass extends BaseClass[String] {
a=""
}
```

java:

```
//...
OtherClass other= new OtherClass();
String a= other.get();
```

javac refuses to compile this, saying there's a type mismatch - `s.get()` returns a Object instead of a String. Why? Is there some way to make java "see" the generic?

Comment: I am no expert on this, but Scalas type system is much more complex and advanced than Javas. So one probably cannot expect that a type parameter in a scala type will map to a Java generic type.

Comment: @Ingo Indeed. I was hoping there was a workaround. What's interesting is that if you try to implement OtherClass in java, BaseClass.a is seen as a **method** that returns a string...

Comment: Your code compiles for me in IntelliJ after supplying a missing end brace. Could you update your question with the error output you're seeing?

Comment: @goncalopp I tried this from the command line and it compiles after inserting a closing brace just before `class OtherClass`. Regarding `var`creating a method, Scala compiles `var`s into 2 methods, `A a()` and `void a_$eq(A)` (i.e., a private variable with a getter and a setter). `javap` is your friend.